# How can I edit custom fields of issues in workflow?

Tags: youtrack

I'm trying to create a workflow which is just like `jetbrains-youtrack-updateFixBuild` but works with my own fields (I have multiple builds for different platforms per task).

Workflow editor does not allow me to modify them. It highlighted my edits in red and does not sync them:
[image: errors in Workflow editor]

Answer (score 0):

Should be fixed by downloading the field scheme from your server (there's a respective button in the toolbar).

Comment: I only see Download / Upload workflows. It does not help.

Comment: Use Ctrl+Space to invoke the completion.

Comment: I see errors in the status bar when it is about to generate suggestions. If you can tell me how to get those logs, I will create a bugreport on your bugtracker.